# Change Screen Resolution of Secondary Monitor in C++

Tags: c++, monitor, screen-resolution

I was wondering if someone could  help me change the screen resolution of the secondary monitor using C++ on Windows 7. I understand this is not much information so if you need more just comment and I'll provide it.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: What OS/platform do you want to target?

Comment: Windows 7, I am using Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 Express.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by setting the correct resolution in a [DEVMODE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd183565.aspx) structure, then calling [ChangeDisplaySettingsEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd183413.aspx) to actually make the change.

You may want to use [EnumDisplaySettingsEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd162612.aspx) to find a resolution supported by the display and graphics card in question.

Comment: for the DEVMODE struct, what do I specify for dmPosition?

Comment: @YahooMania: If you just want to change resolution, only set DM_PELSWIDTH and DM_PELSHEIGHT in `dmFields`, and `dmPosition` will be ignored.

Comment: I tried that, only setting width and height, but that changes the resolution of the primary monitor only

Comment: @YahooMania: You typically start with EnumDisplayDevices to find the right display. Then you use EnumDisplaySettings to find valid settings for that display. Finally, you use ChangeDisplaySettingsEx to set the chosen display to one of the available modes. This does work (i.e., I've written code that successfully changes the resolution on my secondary monitor this way).

Comment: At the risk of sounding incredibly stupid, I can't find EnumDisplayDevices in my libraries. I have included Winuser.h and Windows.h and I can see EnumDisplaySettings but not EnumDisplayDevices :S. Do you know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: @YahooMania: I'm not sure. [The docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd162609.aspx) say it's been present since Win2K, so any *reasonably* recent compiler should have it in the headers/libraries.